# How to account for the common ion effect on osmolarity quantitatively?

Tags: physical-chemistry, equilibrium, analytical-chemistry, ionic-compounds

In adjusting the **osmolarity** of a solution of *Benzalknonium Cl, Disodium Editate, and Disodium borate/boric acid buffer* to be isotonic (**about 290 mOsm**), the addition of NaCl showed unexpected behavior, possibly non-linear.

I strongly suggest that the **common ion effect** plays a role here, but how to account for it quantitatively? in other words how to calculate the amount of molecules of say benzalkonium Cl shifted to undissociated state after addtion of
 NaCl ?

Thanks

Comment: How would you describe the unexpected behavior of NaCl in your mixture ?

Comment: NaCl was added to adjust osmolarity, but the calculated amount of which to acheive isotonicity turned out to be too low  in first time, increseaed osmolarity by only 15 mOsm rather than the required 205 mOsm. In second time increment was too high = 260mOsm while the required was 190 mOsm. The amounts of NaCl were calculated by linear relationship with 0.9 NaCl aqueous solution for which osmolarity=300 mOsm